# How to get values between html tags in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a html string like this

```
<span class="date booking-date">Dec 2, 2015</span><span class="time booking-time">6:36 am</span>
```

I want to get 2 values `Dec 2, 2015` and `6:36` (not include `am`) into 2 variables with PHP, should I use `preg_match` to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting separate values using `preg_match`, you can use `strip_tags` and [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object like:

```
$string = '<span class="date booking-date">Dec 2, 2015</span><span class="time booking-time">6:36 am</span>';
$dateTime = new DateTime(strip_tags($string));

var_dump($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

The output would be

```
string(19) "2015-12-02 06:36:00"
```

The advantage of doing like this is that you can manipulate the date however you want.